# Why store Refresh Token in a HTTP Only Cookie Prevent From CSRF Attack?

Tags: cookies, jwt, refresh-token

I just read an article from this

https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/

In summary, they recommend to store JWT Access Token in memory (as a variable in JavaScript for example) and Refresh Token in HTTP-Only Cookie.

They said:

> But by persisting our session indirectly via a refresh token, we
> prevent a direct CSRF vulnerability we would have had with a JWT
> token.

But is it store Refresh Token in a HTTP-Only cookie still vulnerable to CSRF Attack? For example, evilsite.com can make request to /refreshtoken endpoint to get new JWT access token. What I understand about HTTP-Only cookie is the cookie can't be read from JavaScript but it will automatically be sent whenever make a HTTP request like how the evilsite.com does. (Correct me if i'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Refresh token in a cookie and access token in memory can be a good model if used with care. Hopefully some better guidance will be made available in standards such as [BFF-TMI](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-bertocci-oauth2-tmi-bff/).

The cookie should have these properties and the SameSite property will mean evilsite cannot send it, so that it is good from a CSRF viewpoint.

- HTTP Only
- Secure
- AES256 Encrypted
- SameSite=strict

OWASP's [CSRF Guidance](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) seems to recommend using both SameSite and CSRF tokens together as the preferred option.

Out of interest here is how I'm implementing things in an SPA Code Sample at the moment - in case it is useful to borrow ideas from:

- [SPA OAuth Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts)
- [Back End API OAuth Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.webproxyapi/blob/master/src/core/services/authorizer.ts)

I may change my mind a little as guidance in this area evolves.

**HIGH SECURITY OPTION?**

The current concensus is that the following option is preferred in terms of security, though I am hoping risks and mitigations become better documented over the coming year:

- Keep access tokens out of the browser completely
- Proxy all API calls via the 'back end for front end'
- See this insightful [2021 video](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html)

This option may add complexity in some areas though, and could also limit capabilities in some scenarios.

As is often the case with security, there are trade-offs with other factors, and the solution chosen may depend on data sensitivity and what stakeholders care about.